# How to forward request to next resolver if name not resolved

Tags: coredns

I have multiple upstream resolvers in my coredns config, e.g.:

```
foo.com {
  forward . XX.XX.XX.XX YY.YY.YY.YY ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ
}
```

I want to forward the request to those servers, but only one knows how to resolve a specific query. (e.g.: only ZZ knows how to resolve `a.foo.com`)

How can I forward the request to the next upstream if the first one doesn't know how to resolve the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatelly `forward` alone does not offer `fallthrough` mechanism, so in this situation you would have to use something else. One such solution would be using the alternate plugin (https://coredns.io/explugins/alternate). It is maintained by the own coredns team.

By using the plugin, your configuration:

```
foo.com {
    forward . XX.XX.XX.XX YY.YY.YY.YY ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ
}
```

Would turn into something like:

```
foo.com {
    forward . XX.XX.XX.XX
    alternate NXDOMAIN,SERVFAIL,REFUSED . YY.YY.YY.YY
    alternate NXDOMAIN,SERVFAIL,REFUSED . ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ
}
```

Beware of the fact that the order will be always followed, so the first node would have more pressure than the others. If you don't want that then you would probably need to write your own plugin.

To use the this plugin or  don't forget to recompile coredns with the plugin included in `plugin.cfg` - **before** *forward*.

If you are having trouble building it from source, I wrote a script:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/coredns/coredns
cd coredns/plugin
git clone https://github.com/coredns/alternate
cd ..
sed -i "s/^require/replace github.com\/coredns\/coredns\/plugin\/alternate \=\> ${PWD//\//\\\/}\/plugin\/alternate\n\nrequire/" go.mod
sed -i s/forward:forward/alternate:alternate\\nforward:forward/ plugin.cfg
make
cd ..
```

Basically it downloads coredns and then alternate to one of its subfolders. The first `sed` is the necessary step to tell coredns to include this plugin in the build and the second `sed` instructs `go` to use your local folder that you just downloaded alternate instead of looking in github. Before running `make` I recommend taking out from `plugin.cfg` other plugins you know you won't be using, like etcd, kubernetes, etc.

Comment: now the latest version of coredns isn't compatible with the alternate plugin. However, the latest release version v1.10.1 still works.

Answer (score 1):

The alternate plugin does not come bundled in the executable by default, so you would have to build `coredns` from source.

Another option would be to use multiple upstreams with the forward plugin:

```
foo.com {
    forward . 127.0.0.1:5301 127.0.0.1:5302 127.0.0.1:5303 {
        policy sequential
    }
}
.:5301 {
    forward . XX.XX.XX.XX
}
.:5302 {
    forward . YY.YY.YY.YY
}
.:5303 {
    forward . ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ
}
```

Where it would go from x to z to resolve.